# What is algebra when math experts say "this object is equipped with algebra"

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have a hard time googling this one. A professor sais "this object is equiped with algebra/topology, etc".
The term "equiped with algebra is masked by "6th grade algebra, lets solve a linear/quadratic equation".

But what is an algebra that one can use to equip object? Is it like a group!/field or what?

Comment: What are you asking?  We really can't guess what somebody we don't know meant by some phrase posted without any context.  What is the underlying problem here?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_over_a_field.  The term "algebra" is not only a branch of math, but is also is a vector space on which a reasonable notion of multiplication has been defined.

Comment: I don't recall ever seeing or hearing the phrase "equipped with algebra" until you asked this question. I've seen phrases like "equipped with its Borel $\sigma$-algebra". If you google "borel-sigma-algebra" you'll get dozens of hits for actual Borel $\sigma$-algebras before you see anything that's really just 6th-grade algebra. There are other specific kinds of algebra one could equip an object with. Please write **exactly** what the professor said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on what you’re referring to. The general term “algebra” in (often older) math text can refer to any mathematical scenario when you want to do something with a mathematical object but there is a set of rules and structures limiting you. Like in the ‘algebra of lines’ you have lines and vectors to use, but you have to follow the rules set in linear algebra. Or when working with abstract objects like rings or fields, you have to follow the underlying algebraic rules defined in whatever space you’re working in. That’s about as far as I can take it without knowing more about the situation

Answer (score 1):

If someone says that a space is equipped with a topology $T$, this means that all of the open sets consist of the sets in $T$. For example, if you say $\mathbb{R}$ equipped with the topology generated by open intervals, it means that the open sets in this topology are intervals of the form $(a,b)$, and everything generated by it.

In the case of an algebra, if you have something equipped with a certain algebra, that probably means that the multiplication table is determined by that.

Basically, it sort of depends on the context, but those statements usually are just specifying the structure of the space to be something.